# Angular: Open file dialog upon button click

Tags: file-upload, primeng

I'm using Angular 8. 
Upon button click I want to open a file dialog, select a file and then call an event that will handle this file.

Thank you,
Zvika

I tried the following code in HTML. 
But I do not want anything to be displayed in HTML.

**HTML**

`<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" customUpload="true" auto="true" (uploadHandler)="onOpenFile($event)" accept="application/pdf"></p-fileUpload>`

**ts**

`public onOpenFile (event)
{
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with normal input tag , you can make it hidden, but at least you need one element to trigger the click event. Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwvr3d)

Comment: Is there a way to select the same file more than once? As for now `handle(e)` triggers only if we select a different file from one that was selected

Comment: You need to try something else, as change event has been bind on the file input tag. So it only trigger when it changes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Abhinav Kumar's answer regarding Primeng:

```
  <span pButton label="Import..." icon="pi pi-folder-open" (click)="fileInput.click()">
    <input #fileInput type="file" hidden (change)="doFileInput($event)">
  </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Posting only if it helps someone**

In my case, I wanted to upload the same file twice. Other than that everything was working fine according to [**this example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwvr3d).

To upload the same file twice you need to clear the `value` of `input` after selecting a file. Like in the example below

[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmrwxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much !